# Combine Folders based on Folder Name Batch

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have subfolders with the following naming convention:

```
000026867_20200722_222406_SS24
```

I want to combine the contents of all folders that share the same last portion of the name.  In this case all folders ending in `SS24`.  It will always be after the 3rd underscore, but there is a chance it might be more than 4 characters after the last underscore.

I want all the files in all the folders ending in `SS24` to be in a new folder named, let's say, `All_SS24`

The original folders can be deleted.

```
@Echo off
pushd "C:\path\to\your\base\folder" 
for /f "Tokens=1* Delims=-" %%A in ( 'Dir /B /AD -' ) Do If Not Exist "%%A" ( 
    Ren "%%A-%%B" "%%A"
) Else ( 
    Move /Y "%%A-%%B*" "%%A\" RmDir "%%A-%%B" 
)
PopD
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more or less what you seem to want:

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\path\to\your\base\folder" 
for /f "tokens=1-4*delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "*_*"') do (
    mkdir "%%d">nul 2>&1
    copy "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d\*" "%%d" /Y
    rd "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d" /S /Q
)
popd
```